# How to set string value on the grouped row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I saw the sample of row grouping ag-grid provided. [Auto Column Group](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#auto-column-group)

I need a new feature which I can set string value on the row grouping, such as I need to set "C" on the country column of united states row grouping, set "Y" on the year column of united states row grouping, set "S" on the sport column of united states row grouping.

I am a new guy for ag-grid, I really don't know how to implement this feature?

Could someone help me?

added the picture[image: value on the grouped row]

Comment: Your question is just not clear enough. Please elaborate, maybe with some examples.

Comment: @Viqas thanks for your relay.
I uploaded the picture, but it seems there are some errors that the picture can't be display correctly. 
In the sample of [Auto Column Group](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#auto-column-group), you can see the United States grouped row, child 2008 grouped row, and the rest of no grouped rows. 
There is no value on the Country, Year and Sport columns of United States grouped row in the sample. I wan to add some value on the those columns of United States grouped row. 
Can this feature be implemented?